# I need to change the img depending on the windows width

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, responsive-design

What I want is to make an image change when the window is smaller.

For example when the window is <900px it will be one image. but when the widow is >900 it will be a different image.

I can't figure out how to do this with different window size?

Answer (score 2):

You can use css media queries like this:

```
@media (max-width:900px) {
   #targetElement { background-image: url('...') }
}

@media (min-width:901px) {
   #targetElement { background-image: url('...') }
}
```

[@media](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this jquery:

```
var width = $(window).width(); 
if (width >= 900) {
    //do something
} else {
    //do something else
}
```

Comment: This works, but only one time. If you wrap it in an event listener, it could happen each time the user resizes the page.

Comment: You can wrap up above code in a function and then you can use window.addEventListener("resize", myFunction);

Comment: You can also use $( window ).resize(function() { //call  function here })

Answer (score 0):

You can use media query, and set a display:none for the desired width.

```
<img src="http://*" class="image1"></img>

@media (max-width:900px) { .image1 { display:none } }
```

Comment: Clever approach. You could have 2 images on the page, then use media queries to only show one depending on the width. One disadvantage is that many browsers will load both images on pageload, making this slower.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by CSS as below

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
 #id{/*Your CSS here */} }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will also use jquery to do this:-

```
var width = $(window).width();

if(width > 900){
     $('#img-id').attr('src','path/to/image');
}else{
    $('#img-id').attr('src','path/to/image');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an event listener. Every time the window resizes, have jQuery check the width. If it is above/below a certain threshold, adjust the image. Something like this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var width = $(window).width();
    $("#width-num").html(width);

    if(width > 500) {
        $("#img-change").attr("src", img2);
    } else {
        $("#img-change").attr("src", img1);
    }   
});
```

[See fiddle for example](https://jsfiddle.net/sqsinger/dxaqu0h5/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by jQuery

```
$(window).resize(function() { 
  if($(window).width() > 900){
   $('Your target div').html('<img src="Ur Image" />');
  } 
  else { 
  $('Your target div').html('<img src="Ur Different Image" />'); 
  } 
});
```

Comment: Yes, but this lacks an event listener. I suspect that OP wants to run this each time that the user resizes the window.